# feed method java if-statement

Tags: java, if-statement, methods

`decHungry()` decreases hungry by 10 and `incEnergy()` increases energy by 10. I would like to make sure it does not go past 0 in hungry levels to negative numbers and does not go above 100 in energy levels. How do I do that?

```
protected void feed() {
    System.out.println("\nEating..."); 
    if (hungry <= 90 && hungry >= 0) {
        decHungry();
        incEnergy();
        System.out.println("I've just ate dumplings, my current energy state is " + energy + " and hungry state is " + hungry);
    }
    else { 
        System.out.println ("I have ate enough!"); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Before calling the function you want to make sure that hungry is greater than or equal to 10 and that energy is less than or equal to 90.

```
if(hungry >= 10){
    decHungry();
}
if(energy <=90){
    incEnergy();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest way would probably be to add a check at the end to see if you went out of bounds, and if so return yourself to the bounds.

```
if(hungry<0)hungry=0;
if(energy>100)energy=100;
```

Comment: and if I add syso comments to those statements it will not override my existing syso?

Comment: @user3482500 what is syso?

Answer (score 0):

You should check for that *after* calling the methods `decHungry` and `incEnergy`. If the hungry or energy level exceeds the limits, then set them to the limit value:

```
protected void feed() {
    System.out.println("\nEating...");

    decHungry();
    incEnergy();

    if (hungry < 0)
        hungry = 0;

    if (energy > 100)
        energy = 100;

    // ...
}
```